# Using svcutil to adjust specific values on bindings

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

I am using svcutil to generate a proxy file for use against a service we consume. Currently, I have a batch file that we can run at anytime to regenerate the proxy file if the service changes. However, I always have to adjust a few values on the bindings after the proxy file generation. Some examples of the changes I need to make are to maxbuffersize, maxreceivedmessagesize and sendtimeout.

Are there any switches to adjust these values as part of the generation process or does it need to be done via post processing of the generated client?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0a\bin\SvcUtil.exe"
>   /tcv:Version35 /config:Proxy.config /t:code
>   https://myserviceprovider.com/Webservices/FirstService.svc?wsdl
>   /out:FirstServiceClient.cs 
>   /namespace:"http://FirstService/services/","MyServices.FirstService"
>
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0a\bin\SvcUtil.exe"
>   /tcv:Version35 /config:Proxy.config /t:code
>   https://myserviceprovider.com/Webservices/SecondService.svc?wsdl
>   /out:SecondServiceClient.cs /mergeConfig
>   /namespace:"http://SecondService/services/","MyServices.SecondService"
>   ...

So in the above example, the first statement creates the Proxy.config file, and the second command uses /merge to merge what is generated by the second statment with the first. In reality there are a few other commands after these and I end up with a Proxy.config file that allows me to connect with the webservice. The problem is, the generated Proxy.Config has some example bindings like the following;

```
                <binding name="FirstServiceBasicHttpEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
```

In the XML snippet above, I've already adjusted the maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize but I'd be keen to know if it were possible to do this as part of a svcutil switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tweak the svcutil.exe.config as demonstrated in this post: http://enterpriseframework.com/post/2009/04/09/Using-a-External-Configuration-file-for-SvcUtilexe-to-generate-a-WCF-Service-Proxy.aspx

> You may come across a situation in which a Service you are trying to create a proxy for is very large and you may receive maxStringContentLength size is to small errors or increase maxNameTableCharCount size errors.  You may need to tweek the settings in order for the proxy to be created.  I recommend you copy the SvcUtil.exe and SvcUtil.exe.config file into a Temp folder and just run it from there.  You can then modify the SvcUtil.exe.config at will to fit your needs.

Comment: This looks really promising. I'll take a look when I get an opportunity.

Comment: Link provided is dead now. [Web.archive version](https://web.archive.org/web/20120210090509/http://enterpriseframework.com/post/2009/04/09/Using-a-External-Configuration-file-for-SvcUtilexe-to-generate-a-WCF-Service-Proxy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx), you should be able to use the `/noConfig` option when you call `svcutil` so that no configuration is generated. If you need to generate some configuration you might want to try `/mergeConfig` option.

Comment: At this point, I am using the /config switch to define the output file. I'll edit my question with an example of some of the commands generated in my batch file to show you my usage of it.

Comment: But do you need to regenerate the config each time? It sounds like you want it fixed, not generated.

Comment: The service we are consuming is still in development (albeit in the late stages) and changes from time to time. Therefore, we need to regenerate the proxy on occasion. In an attempt to automate all steps and remove any manual intervention, I was keen to simply have one batch script that performed the generation along with our changes. I am leaning towards a search replace post generation.